# Are all tangent planes along a fixed coordinate curve parallel?

Tags: differential-geometry

I have tried this question several times, but I always find a contradiction. And the contradiction is that for a constant $u=uo$, $Xu$ is $(0,0,0)$ and $Xv$=$α₂′(v)$. But, {$Xu$,$Xv$} is a basis for $\mathbb TpS$ at $p=X(uo,v)$. Could anyone clarify my doubts?
Thanks!

[image]

Comment: How do you conclude $X_{u} = (0, 0, 0)$? (Remember: Differentiate _first_, then evaluate at $u = u_{0}$. It matters!)